# Fastlane no such file or directory for files that exist

Tags: ios, ruby, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm trying to setup fastlane to use some files for values in my Deliverfile. These files are in a directory under `ProjectRoot/fastlane/shared_metadata/`

So, in my Deliverfile I'm using: `release_notes File.read("./shared_metadata/release_notes.txt")`  and when I run my lane it fails telling me

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./shared_metadata/release_notes.txt

However, in my lane, if I run the same command, `releaseNotes = File.read("./shared_metadata/release_notes.txt")` the var releaseNotes contains my file's contents as normal.

I've checked `pwd` multiple times and it is `ProjectRoot/fastlane/` so I can't figure out why fastlane does not see the files.

Fastlane keeps returning no such file or directory, even for files in the `/fastlane/` directory. What is causing this behaviour, and how can I fix it?